# Two instances of class are getting mixed up?

Tags: class, timer, processing

I am creating a sort of game with Arduino and Processing. In my code, I use Daniel Shiffman's class Timer, but would like to create two different Timers using two different instances of the class.

My problem is that these two instances seem to be getting mixed up, with each one doing parts of what the other should be doing.

For example, timer should run for 10 seconds and correctTimer should run for 3 seconds, but they both run for 10 seconds. Additionally, when timer is finished, it should set the background to red and when correctTimer is finished, it should set the background to blue. However, both Timers set the background to blue when they are finished.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to fix this?

```java
import processing.serial.*;
int end = 10;
String serial;
Serial port;
float[] array;

// --------------------------------------------------

PImage img;
PImage correct;
PImage incorrect;
float thumb;
float index;
float middle;
float ring;
float pinky;

// --------------------------------------------------

String alphabet;
int randomNum;
String letter;

// --------------------------------------------------

int savedTime;
int totalTime;
int passedTime;
boolean quit = false;
class Timer { 
  Timer(int tempTotalTime) {
    totalTime = tempTotalTime;
  }
  void start() {
    savedTime = millis();
    //quit = false;
  }
  boolean isFinished() {
    passedTime = millis() - savedTime;
    if (passedTime > totalTime) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
Timer timer;
Timer correctTimer;

// --------------------------------------------------  

boolean checkLetter(String letterPicked, float flexR_THUMB, float flexR_INDEX, float flexR_MIDDLE, float flexR_RING, float flexR_PINKY) {
  if (letterPicked == "A") {  
    if (flexR_THUMB > 12000 && flexR_THUMB < 22000 &&
        flexR_INDEX > 27958 && flexR_INDEX < 38500 &&
        flexR_MIDDLE > 26035 && flexR_MIDDLE < 41650 &&
        flexR_RING > 16492 && flexR_RING < 26000 &&
        flexR_PINKY > 37528 && flexR_PINKY < 53500) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
    }  
  }
return false; } 

// --------------------------------------------------  

void setup() {
  size(1280, 950);
  background(255);

  port = new Serial(this, "/dev/tty.usbmodem1421", 9600);
  port.clear();
  serial = port.readStringUntil(end);
  serial = null;

  correct = loadImage("img/RIGHT.png");
  incorrect = loadImage("img/WRONG.png");
  correctTimer = new Timer(3000);

  startOver();
}

// --------------------------------------------------

void startOver() {
  background(255);

  letter = "A";

  img = loadImage("img/" + letter +".png");
  image(img, 0, 0, 1280, 950);
  timer = new Timer(10000);
  timer.start();
}

// --------------------------------------------------    

void draw() {
  while(port.available() > 0) {
    serial = port.readStringUntil(end);
  }

  if (serial != null) {
    float[] array = float(split(serial, ','));
    thumb = array[0];
    index = array[1];
    middle = array[2];
    ring = array[3];
    pinky = array[4];
  }

  if (checkLetter(letter, thumb, index, middle, ring, pinky) == true && quit == false) {
    image(correct, 0, 0, 1280, 950);
    quit = true;
    correctTimer.start();
  } else if (timer.isFinished() && quit == false) {
    background(255, 0, 0);
    quit = true;
    correctTimer.start();
  }

  if (correctTimer.isFinished()) {
    background(0, 0, 255);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of your whole project. Just put together a small example that demonstrates the problem. That makes it much easier for us to help you.

But your problem is caused by your `savedTime`, `totalTime`, and `passedTime` variables being outside the `Timer` class. Basically that means they're shared between all instances of the `Timer` class. You can use `println()` statements to confirm this.

To fix your problem, just move those variables inside the `Timer` class, so each instance has its own copy of them.

If you're still having trouble, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question post, and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry about that- I am new to Stack Overflow. Thank you for your answer but the problem persists. I will make a new post.